# Socket.io "emitting but not responding"

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm working on a realtime socket.io project.
It will be a collabrative whiteboard app.
I have trouble with emitting.

server.js

```
 const express = require('express')
const app = express();
const http = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http, {
    cors: {
        origin: '*',
    }
});
app.use('/',express.static('ui'))

var connections = []

io.on('connect', (socket) => {
    
    connections.push(socket)
    console.log(`${socket.id} has connected`);

    io.emit('currentCanvas')
    //socket.emit('currentCanvas') both of these doesnt work

    socket.on('image-data', (imageData) =>{
        socket.emit('setImageData', imageData);
    })

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        connections = connections.filter((cn) => cn.id !== socket.id);
        console.log(`${socket.id} is disconnected`);
    })

    socket.on('draw', (data) => {
        socket.broadcast.emit('onDraw',data)
    })
    
    socket.on('down',(data) =>{
        socket.broadcast.emit('onDown',data)
    } ) 

})

http.listen(5000, () => console.log('listening on port 5000'));
```

After a client connect i cant emmit "current canvas"

```
    var canvas = document.getElementById('my-canvas');

canvas.width = 0.98 * window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = 0.9 * window.innerHeight;

var io = io();
 
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let x,y;
let lineActive = false;

canvas.addEventListener('click',(e) => {
    lineActive = !lineActive
    ctx.moveTo(x, y)
    io.emit('down',{x,y})
})

io.on('onDraw', (data) => {
    ctx.lineTo(data.x,data.y)
    ctx.stroke();
})

io.on('onDown', (data) => {
    lineActive = !lineActive
    ctx.moveTo(data.x, data.y)
})

io.on('currentCanvas', () =>{
    var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height)
    console.log(io.id + "current-canvas alındı");
    //io.emit('image-data',imageData)
});

io.on('deneme', () =>{
    console.log('deneme');
})

io.on('setImageData',(imageData) =>{
    ctx.putImageData(imageData,0,0)
})

window.onmousemove = (e)=>{
    x = e.clientX;
    y = e.clientY;

    if(lineActive){
        io.emit("draw",{x,y})
        ctx.lineTo(x,y)
        ctx.stroke();
    }
}
```

When I look from debug, I understand that it is emitted by the server, but not received from client

debug terminal

[image]

i have no idea what it could be. thanks in advance.

Comment: wrap all your clientside event definitions and logic in a `socket.on('connect', () => {` move the `io.emit('currentCanvas')` to the bottom of the server part, your firing just as its connected

Comment: How are you using this in the client side? May be you are missing the payload of the message.

Answer (score 0):

Lawrence Cherone find the solution in the comment side.

wrap all your clientside event definitions and logic in a socket.on('connect', () => { move the io.emit('currentCanvas') to the bottom of the server part, your firing just as its connected